# Ember handlebars concat string and variable always appends white space

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

```
var categories = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']

{{#each categories as |item|}}
  {{concat ',' item}}
{{/each}}
```

will produce:
,item1 ,item2 ,item3

How do i remove the whitespace before each string?

Comment: You could try removing the whitespace between each and it's contents, `{{#each categories as |item|}}{{concat ',' item}}{{/each}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove whitespace by using the `~` modifier:

```
var categories = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']

{{#each categories as |item|}}
  {{~ concat ',' item ~}}
{{/each}}
```

This will remove whitespace before and after. See the [Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/8defbea7afe72b9e1c9a72b4b347f487?fileTreeShown=false&numColumns=2&openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ctemplates.application.hbs) for a working reproduction, and [Handlebar.js' documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html) under "Whitespace Control" for more information.